# How to add right padding to the current line number in emacs in nlinum-mode

Tags: linum-mode

[image]I'd like to make current line number in relative line number mode more distinguishable

```
(setq nlinum-format-function 'myformat)
(defun myformat (line width)
  (if
    (eq line (what-line)) "123  "
    "321"
  )
)
```

Notice padding to the right of the current line number in vim which very subtly makes it easily distinguishable.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to do, and include only code that is relevant to that task.  Please explain what you want that code to do, and what happens instead.

Comment: I'm trying to add padding to the right of the current line number. I was just experimenting and I was expecting to see `123  ` as the current line number and `321` on every other line.

Answer (score 1):

package `nlinum` has option `nlinum-format`.
You can set option to value like this: `(setq nlinum-format "%d ")`. Just like package `linum` can be configured like this: `(setq linum-format "%4d \u2502")`.

Comment: Don't you think it would affect all line numbers and not only the current one? Spoiler alert -> it would. Read question more carefully before answering.

Comment: @user1685095 : please keep it polite.

Comment: @Dan What's impolite about my comment? Or is polite and I should "keep it" that way?

Comment: Maybe can try a lambda function which is dynamic to decide whether current line as value. BTW, don't be too mean.

Comment: @stardiviner Thanks, cap! Can you show how to do that in elisp and nlinum?

Comment: Like this: `(setq nlinum-format (lambda () (if (current-line) "%d" "%d ")))`. But this is just an idea. It need to be `funcall`. I don't know how the nlinum use this `nlinum-format` variable. On another idea is to dive into source code, and try to add an advice.